# Googlemaps on android is showing grey screen

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I've just gotten my google maps application to not crash on startup, but now, when it opens, it just shows a grey/white background and buttons for zooming. I searched the web and I found that this may be a problem with my API-key, so I got a new key from google, but this didn't work either.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks.
[link to image](http://s7.postimage.org/u6ntgzh3v/Screenshot_2013_01_08_17_53_00.png) (I'm a new user, so I couldn't post a picture here)

Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidbasic12"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    >
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<permission 
    android:name="come.example.androidbasics12.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission      
        android:name="com.example.androidbasics12.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/new_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- First xml to be loaded -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidbasic12.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"   />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Opens main menu after splash has loaded -->
        <activity
            android:name=".myMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidbasic12.CLEARSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Opens test -->
        <activity
            android:name=".tutOne"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidbasic12.TUTONE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!-- Opens map page -->
        <activity
            android:name=".map"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.androidbasic12.MAPS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBcMOBc8WVLUIRUfs0Zgap3cnhwm4dWLag"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone got any tips for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem as you, everything worked ok on emulator but on the real device it was gray surface with zoom buttons. 
Then I tried other devices and it works. All other phones have original (stock) firmware, only I have one with custom firmware.

lease first check that everything works fine on emulator, then check on the device with stock firmware and let us know the result.

Comment: I currently have problems starting my emulator, I will respond as soon as I've got it to work!

Comment: After alot of work, getting "You need Google play to run Google maps" on emulator, but finally I got it working! How come this works on the emulator but not on my real device?

Comment: Does your real device have stock firmware or custom one?

Comment: But, as iagreen mentioned, first check is everything OK with your API key.

Comment: I guess I use stock firmware, as I haven't installed any custom firmware. As I said in a comment below, I got it working on my device after running the app on a emulator, and another device.

Comment: Strange, but that's Android after all :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be with your API key, but the authorized apps in the API console. Make sure you registered the correct key(s) and package names with the Google API console.  Specifically, if you are compiling and launching directly from eclipse, you are probably signing in [debug mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode).  If so, you need to add your debug key hash + package name to the allowed applications in the API console.

Comment: I got it working on my own device after sucessfully trying it on a emulator and another phone and then it miraculously worked on my device. It seems weird but then everything I've experienced with android is.